# always on availability group with different speed disks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, storage, availability-groups

I'm looking to set up SQL Server 2012 installation with an Always On Availability Group, where the 'passive' replica will be hosted at another site on the WAN and using synchronous data commit - the idea being that we will have a hot standby with no loss of data in the event of a failure at our primary site.

One potential problem that I foresee is that the secondary site has slower storage than our primary site.  I don't care about that in the event of a failure, we can live with slow speeds for a period of time until the primary site is restored.  My worry is that, because we are using synchronous commit, that the slower disk speed at the secondary site will affect performance at the primary site during normal operation.

Is this a valid concern, or is it likely that the slower speed will be offset by, for example, the disk not having much read activity in comparison to the primary site?

Comment: The writes on your primary will only be as fast as the writes on your secondary. I would probably at least consider asynchronous commit in that case (and perhaps have a synchronous replica more locally - such that data loss is only really a concern if the whole site goes down instead of a single server).

Comment: But the secondary has no read load on the discs - it may well be that the slower discs are in fact faster than the fast discs because they carry a lot less load - depends heavily on the operations done on the server.

Comment: @TomTom in a lot of systems there is very little read load on the disk, because ideally all of the data is in memory, and almost all of the load is write.

Comment: I don't dispute that - just saying that this is the case. On other systems you have IO problems.

Comment: Good points. I can't really create a synchronous replica locally though as there just isn't the disk space for it.  And zero data loss is important so I don't really want to have just asynchronous replication. I guess it's the usual situation - Speed/Cost/Resilience: choose any two!  :-)

Comment: If zero data loss is important, then get the person who says it is important to spend some money to make it possible. No disk space is a poor excuse for making compromises in fault tolerance and DR.

Comment: There are a lot of variables in this scenario. Really the only way to figure out an answer is to test it.

Comment: 1. How far away is this replica? I think the network latency will be much worse than the disk speed. Most of the disk IO will be on the transaction log, which is sequential and performs well on disks. 2. How busy is your primary disk?

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is pretty much what I've done.  I just needed to make sure that I knew what I was talking about first.

Comment: @JohnTseng We have a gigabit link to the secondary site a few miles away.  This is for a new system that I don't have any specific information for yet (we're expecting it to be 'busy' but more reads than writes).  The disks at the secondary site are only writing at about 30MB/s, which I believe is not very fast.